# Specific Names not showing up in database query

Tags: mysql

We have a MySQL database with hundreds of names. Included are 3 entries for the name Down.

These do not show up when we perform a php Search. The same search will find the entry if I change the name in the table to Downe, but disappears as soon as change it back to Down.

If I perform a Search for another item in a Down entry (say birthplace) then Search finds this and presents the Down item in its entirety.

The same thing happens with a second table that also contains entries for Down.

Comment: Please edit your question to include table & index definitions and the query.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get to the answer via the response from ypercube below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shown the query but I guess you are doing full-text search. In full text searches, several words do not show up in the results. Such words are too short ones (3 characters or less) and the ones defined as "Stopwords".

From MySQL docs, [Natural Language Full-Text Searches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-natural-language.html):

> Some words are ignored in full-text searches:
>
> - Any word that is too short is ignored. The default minimum length of words that are found by full-text searches is four characters.
> - Words in the stopword list are ignored. A stopword is a word such as “the” or “some” that is so common that it is considered to have zero semantic value. There is a built-in stopword list, but it can be overwritten by a user-defined list.

"down" is in the [Full-Text Stopwords list](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html), that's why it doesn't appear in the results, while "downe" does appear.

---

You could override this stopword list, as described in [Fine-Tuning MySQL Full-Text Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html):

> - To override the default stopword list, set the `ft_stopword_file` system variable. (See [Section 5.1.4, “Server System Variables”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html).) The variable value should be the path name of the file containing the stopword list, or the empty string to disable stopword filtering. The server looks for the file in the data directory unless an absolute path name is given to specify a different directory. After changing the value of this variable or the contents of the stopword file, restart the server and rebuild your `FULLTEXT` indexes.
>
>   The stopword list is free-form. That is, you may use any nonalphanumeric character such as newline, space, or comma to separate stopwords. Exceptions are the underscore character (“_”) and a single apostrophe (“'”) which are treated as part of a word. The character set of the stopword list is the server's default character set; see [Section 10.1.4.1, “Server Character Set and Collation”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-server.html).

Comment: and overriding the stop words has side effects, if it is in use for real text. At the end: Full text search is unsuited for use with names and other non-text "particles".

Comment: This is exactly the right answer. Thank you so much for pointing me towards it. I previously had no idea a stopword list existed. In a shared server environment I don't think it's possible to mod the stopword list because that is controlled by the hosting service, so I guess we will have to find another workaround (we recoded the names 'Down' to 'Downe' and provided a note as to why with a warning on the Search page itself: hardly elegant but the best we could think of.)